# Error: Cannot find module 'Babel-register' using Ubuntu, what am I missing here?

Tags: ubuntu

I am currently working on a project using Sublime, Gnache, and Ubuntu to create this project.  I have gotten to the point of the project that when instructed to use "Truffle compile" in Ubuntu i get the following response.

[babel-register issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Tp8M.png)

I have tried different things from other related questions, except for 'Deleting the package-lock json file' and deleting the 'node_module folder'and doing the nmp install.

I believe it is a internal conflict of versions of software, I would like an outside viewpoint as well as options to resolving this issue, much thanks in advance for this help.

Comment: Please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557)